# Calculate risk of unrelated groups

Tags: risk-assessment

Let's say we have a few variables (made up numbers). Each percentage is a risk of failure later in life.

#### Gender

- Male 10%
- Woman 20%

#### Age

- 25 years: 2%
- 50 years: 5%
- 70 years: 7%

#### Interests

- Fotball: 10%
- Baseball: 40%
- Golf: 60%

### Question

How can I calculate the risk of for example a `male` that is `25 years` old interested in `golf`?

### What I thought of so far - That did not work

1. First I thought I could make an avarage right across the board. But then I figured that inside the percentage on for example `50 years`, genders is already accounted for. The groups gender, age and interests are self contained groups unaware of each other.
2. One person can have multiple interests which also mess up my thoughts.

How should I think around this case? I'm not a math experts so in case you add formulas, also add the thought process behind it.

Comment: Important point: you need to know if all the "events" are independent. For example, are the events "male" and "football" independent? If not, it could be that only men like football! (because the percentages are the same)

Comment: @MattiP. In the interests group there are `fotball`, `baseball` and `golf`. In this group there can be both male and female and the group does not know (or not care) about the gender within this group.

Comment: So the percentages are to be interpreted like this: If you like golf, there's a 60% chance that you will fail at some point", right?

Comment: @MattiP.Yes, that is correct.

Comment: That's some really odd logic here ... So as with any probability question, I would start making shorthand notations. Let $P(X)=\text{probability that the person will fail at some point}$. Now the probabilities listed are something like
$$
P(X| \text{male}) = 0.1 \qquad P(X| \text{female}) = 0.2
$$

Comment: For your question, I think the rule of product (independent events) would be useful. But I have a hunch feeling that the numbers provided are not very realistic.

Comment: @MattiP. Not sure about this but maybe it would be possible to calculate each group first. Then in the next step somehow combine them to one results. The problem is that if I'm a 70 year old woman that plays golf I maximize the risk in all cases. Then maybe 60% would be correct? But an avarage would be maybe 40%.